# Alpha numeric preg_replace ignoring unichars

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I'm trying to use `preg_replace` to replace everything but chars nums and unicode chars.
This is what I have tried and getting this error:

> preg_replace(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 22

Here is my regex:

`[^A-Za-z0-9 \x{0080}-\x{FFFF}]`

I'm wanting to transform the text to something like the following example:

`CAFÉ? CREATORS WERE HERE!#1` =>  `CAFÉ CREATORS WERE HERE1`

-- EDIT --

I tried the solution below and got this error:

```
$str = 'CAFÉ? CREATORS WERE HERE!#1';


$alphaNumStr = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 x{0080}-x{FFFF}]/u', '', $str);

echo 'TEXT: ' . $alphaNumStr;
```

> TEXT: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 20 on line 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep all letters in all languages, use:

```
$str = 'CAFÉ? CREATORS WERE HERE!#1';
echo preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\d\s]+/u', '', $str);
```

**Output:**

```
CAFÉ CREATORS WERE HERE1
```

`\p{L}` stands for any letter.

[Further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category)

Comment: Hi im just starting a meeting now, but im still having issues. I'll get back to you soon

Comment: I chose this as the answer as I feel its a little more elegant

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `u` (unicode) flag to your regex:

```
$text = 'CAFÉ? CREATORS WERE HERE!#1';
echo preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 \x{0080}-\x{FFFF}]/u', '', $text);
```

Output

```
CAFÉ CREATORS WERE HERE1
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/r7SBQ)

Comment: I edited the answer based on your answer. Please let me know if you see anything that I'm doing wrong. Thank you

Comment: You're missing the `\ ` in front of the `x`

Comment: Hi im just starting a meeting now, but im still having issues with yours also in my code. I'll get back to you soon.

Comment: @TheMan68 I don't understand why - I've given you links to two working demos... but when you copied the code last time, somehow you lost a backslash, perhaps that has happened again.